# Colab uploaded ipynb file failed to open

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I downloaded an `ipynb` file which I haven been previously working on in Colab because the file failed to save halfway. Then after I uploaded the file to Google Drive, it failed to open.

Usually there is an "Open with Colab" option upon clicking on the file:
[image]

but this time

[image]

Why is this happening and what do I have to do to continue working on the saved file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to navigate to http://colab.research.google.com/ and click the "Upload" tab in the dialog, and upload your notebook directly.

If Colab is unable to read your notebook when you do this, it means the file has been corrupted (i.e. it is not valid JSON) and you'll have to fix it locally before Colab will be able to read it.

Comment: I could open the file now. Thank you so much!